# Can next state and action be same in Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl

I am trying to apply deep deterministic policy gradient (DDPG) on a robotic application. My states consist of the joint angle positions of the robot and my actions are also its joint angle positions. Since, DDPG produces a continuous policy output where states are directly mapped onto the actions, can I say that my next state and action will be same? Simplistically, the input of the policy network will be the current state and the output will be the next state?

Comment: Hi and welcome to this community! What do you mean by "my actions are also its joint angle positions"?

Comment: Thanks,  what I mean is that my actions are the next joint angle positions. For example: the current position (state) is 90 degrees and the action (next state) could be 91 degrees and so on. Actually, I am very confused with the design of action map for my problem, and the idea of continuous action spaces.